# mysql find duplicate values across columns in different tables

Tags: mysql

Given 3 tables A, B and C, each of the tables have a id column which must be unique across the three tables. How do i do a query to do that? right now I am using left join and find the count, but it will not work as this particular id may exists in only one of the three tables

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) as unique_id FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B on B.id= A.id
        LEFT JOIN Con B.id= C.id
 WHERE A.id='{$id}'
    OR B.id='{$id}'
    OR C.id='{$id}'
```

i am trying to find out if this $id is unique among the three tables.

Comment: How do you query what? Are you trying to get a list of all non-unique IDs?

Comment: i am trying to find out if this $id is unique among the three tables.

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL doesn't have FULL OUTER JOIN, you have to use a UNION.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as unique_id
FROM (SELECT id FROM A WHERE id = '$id'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id FROM B WHERE id = '$id'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id FROM C WHERE id = '$id') x
```

Comment: `UNION` combines like rows, so you would need to add something to the `SELECT` in each to make them distinct

Comment: @WillPalmer UNION DISTINCT combines them, UNION ALL doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following

```
SELECT 
(
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE id = 3)
 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE id = 3)
 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C WHERE id = 3)
) unique_count
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d554e/2)** demo

**Now** instead of finding duplicates and assigning ids manually you might want to consider to make them unique across your tables by utilizing a separate table for sequencing with `auto_increment` and simple triggers.

Your db schema might look like

```
CREATE TABLE id_seq (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE A (id INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE B (id INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE C (id INT NOT NULL);
```

Triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_a_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON a
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO id_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

*They will be the same for all tables. Just change the name of a trigger and table*

Now you can `INSERT` to any of you tables like

```
INSERT INTO A (id) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO B (id) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO C (id) VALUES (0);
```

And you will get

```
Table A
| ID |
------
|  1 |

Table B
| ID |
------
|  2 |

Table C
| ID |
------
|  3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25324/1)** demo